# In GCP python cloud function, dataframe is putting ' ' in the end while reading csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

[image: Image is of csv file I'm using for testing]In GCP, my python cloud function is adding ' ' as last row while reading csv file in to JSON format through pandas data frame. ex:-

```
['{"LANG_TK":"19","LANG_CODE":"ar","CLU_CODE_CHILD":"BH","CLUT_TYPE_CHILD":"RU","GA_CODE_PARENT":"BH","CLT_CLASS_CHILD":"GR","GA_TYPE_PARENT":"CTY","GACONT_TYPE":"PROC","FILE_TYPE":"RULU"}', '{"LANG_TK":"19","LANG_CODE":"ar","CLU_CODE_CHILD":"JO","CLUT_TYPE_CHILD":"RU","GA_CODE_PARENT":"JO","CLT_CLASS_CHILD":"GR","GA_TYPE_PARENT":"CTY","GACONT_TYPE":"PROC","FILE_TYPE":"RULU"}', '']
```

The same python code when I'm running in Pycharm, I'm getting no ' ' & it runs successful. ex:-

```
['{"LANG_TK":"19","LANG_CODE":"ar","CLU_CODE_CHILD":"BH","CLUT_TYPE_CHILD":"RU","GA_CODE_PARENT":"BH","CLT_CLASS_CHILD":"GR","GA_TYPE_PARENT":"CTY","GACONT_TYPE":"PROC","FILE_TYPE":"RULU"}', '{"LANG_TK":"19","LANG_CODE":"ar","CLU_CODE_CHILD":"JO","CLUT_TYPE_CHILD":"RU","GA_CODE_PARENT":"JO","CLT_CLASS_CHILD":"GR","GA_TYPE_PARENT":"CTY","GACONT_TYPE":"PROC","FILE_TYPE":"RULU"}']
```

This is creating error while publishing in to pubsub because it is getting empty row ' ' in json as last row. Below is the code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
import csv
import json
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def check_endchar(event, context):
    """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    file = event
    print(f"Processing file: {file['name']}.")
    print(f"file :{file}.")
    dataframe = pd.read_csv('gs://abc/cbd/sync/cbd-data/CBD_Languageru.csv', encoding='utf-8', dtype=str,)

    dataframe = dataframe.assign(FILE_TYPE='RULU')
    print(dataframe)
    data = dataframe.to_json(orient="records", lines=True).split('\n')
    print(data)
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    topic_1 = publisher.topic_path('abc', 'test-dev')
    for data in data:
     data = data.encode("utf-8")
     response_1 = publisher.publish(topic_1, data=data)
```

I have already tried deleting the last empty row by putting like this :

```
usersDf = pd.read_csv('users.csv', skipfooter=2, engine='python')
```

But this deletes the last row & again add ' ' in the end. somehow this empty row is only coming in Google cloud function. It doesn't come when I run it in pycharm. The test csv file is attached as image here. The requirements.txt file content is mentioned below:

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
google.cloud.storage
google.cloud.datastore
google-cloud-pubsub
pandas
fsspec
gcsfs
```

Comment: Please upload your sample csv as text rather than image.

Comment: Are you using the same Python version on both local and Cloud Functions? Update your post as well and include the version.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7 on both GCP & Pycharm

Comment: I forgot to ask, please include your dependencies versions as well. Especially pandas

Comment: I haven't given versions in requirements.txt file because the cloud function automatically fetches the latest version for any dependency.. Do you think this might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by explicitly putting version pandas==1.1.3 in requirements.txt. Since my earlier requirements.txt didn't have any version mentioned, it was actually fetching the latest version of pandas which is 1.3.0  right now. This latest version  is actually adding ' ' in the end of row while reading with 'lines =True' in pd.read()

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on the dependency itself rather than Cloud Functions as I was able to replicate this problem on my machine with Python 3.8 and Pandas 1.2.0 installed.

To remove the empty row, remove "lines" on `dataframe.to_json`:

```
data = dataframe.to_json(orient="records").split('\n')
```

Or simply call it like this:

```
data = dataframe.to_json(orient="records")
```

However, the formatting may slightly change. I suggest you lower your dependency versions (pandas) if that's an issue.

Comment: "lines= True" is actually making the json message to be read line by line .If I remove it, it sends entire JSON msg in one go & it ruptures the structure of data in pubsub   I am further processing this data in datastore & thus reading that data while exposing API.Hence, I want JSON message to be read line by line only